# What loot tables have mending?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I am looking for a list of chests that are able to have mending (either on an enchanted book or a "treasure" item).

I remember seeing a list on the wiki a long time ago but it does not seem to have that anymore.

What loot tables have mending books/items?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So as I could not find an answer online, I just manually searched every loot table in the game to get an answer which I have now added to [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Summary_of_enchantments).

But anyways here we go:

**Treasure enchantments (Mending, Frost Walker, Curse of Binding, and Curse of Vanishing) can be obtained from the following:**

- Jungle Temples (enchanted books)
- Stronghold coridor, crossing, and library (enchanted books)
- Fishing (both enchanted books and items)
- End Cities (only items, not enchanted books)
- Librarian villager trades (enchanted books)

**Update:** The aforementioned are chests that can roll books guaranteed to be "treasure enchantments" such as mending. However, there are a few other loot tables in the game that have "randomly enchanted" books that I was not aware apparently have a chance (small though it be) to be a treasure enchantment as well. These include:

- Dungeons
- Mineshafts
- Ancient Cities
- Desert temples
- Pillager Outposts
- Underwater ruins (big)
- Woodland Mansions

Comment: what about desert temples? can they not have mending books?

Comment: looks like according to [this wiki page](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Enchanted_Book#cite_ref-enchant-randomly_2-1) mending books can be generated any time an "enchanted book" is in a loot table, such as  dungeon chests, mineshaft chests, ancient cities, pillager outpost, underwater ruins, and woodland mansions.

Comment: I was not aware the books "enchanted randomly" included treasure enchants, also I'm not even sure if that's true. I'll have to verify